# Dumping unicode with YAML

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, ruamel.yaml

I'm creating yaml files from csv's that have a lot of unicode characters in them but I can't seem to get it to dump the unicode without it giving me a Decode Error.

I'm using the `ruamel.yaml` library.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried parsing strings, unicode strings, encoding with "utf-8" nothing seems to work. I've seen a lot of examples that show adding a representer to solve the issue but they all seem to be using the old method for ruamel and I can't seem to find out how to do that in the newer method documented anywhere.

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

class YamlObject(YAML):
    def __init__(self):
        YAML.__init__(self)
        self.default_flow_style = False
        self.block_seq_indent = 2
        self.indent = 4
        self.allow_unicode = True

textDict = {"text": u"HELLO_WORLD©"}
textFile = "D:\\testFile.yml"
yaml = YamlObject()
yaml.dump(textDict, file(textFile, "w"))
```

I can unicode the entire dict and that works but it doesn't give me the format I need back.

What I need is just:

```
text: HELLO_WORLD©
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @jwodder Python2 of course (`file` is not a internal in Python 3)

Comment: Yes, it's Python 2. Sorry should've said!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `encoding` in your derived `YAML` object.

Try like this:

```
class YamlObject(YAML):
    def __init__(self):
        YAML.__init__(self)
        self.default_flow_style = False
        self.block_seq_indent = 2
        self.indent = 4
        self.allow_unicode = True
        self.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

If you [look at the definition of your base class, `YAML`](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/8b6c70d5656c40564e7e9a0f1bf4f867abc4f59e/main.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#main.py-121), you'll notice that by default, `encoding` is undefined:

```
self.encoding = None
```

and it stays `None` through [`YAML.dump()`](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/8b6c70d5656c40564e7e9a0f1bf4f867abc4f59e/main.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#main.py-338) and `YAML.dump_all()`. In the global [`dump()`](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/8b6c70d5656c40564e7e9a0f1bf4f867abc4f59e/main.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#main.py-770) method, on contrary, `encoding` is set to a default `utf-8` (in Python 2 only).

**Update**. This actually is a bug in `ruamel.yaml` for Python 2 (Thanks @Anthon).

Comment: You're welcome. When in doubt, always check the source. That's the beauty of open source. :) Btw, you can check it easily on disk, but I needed a reference to cite.

Comment: @randomir This actually is a bug in ruamel.yaml. Using the YAML object, [self.allow_unicode is always True](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/8b6c70d5656c40564e7e9a0f1bf4f867abc4f59e/main.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#main.py-69). Since the `dump()` you indicate is not the method used, you're pointing to the `dump()` global function of the old API. This also goes wrong when using `yaml.dump()` without setting `self.allow_unicode` explicitly to `True`, and it shouldn't.

Comment: @Anthon, thanks for the update. Looks like `encoding` is set to a default `enc='utf-8'`, but to `None` in YAML object. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: This is now [tested](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/2780a38bd1264bc6acb32b3361756ae23211b6e9/_test/test_api_change.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#test_api_change.py-130) and should be fixed in 0.15.21